# cuando bugeo no entra al ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

Estoy mandando un `onclick` a esta function en javascript, si capturo los datos de "x" y "y",
pero no entra al ajax y se va hasta la ultima llave.

Como puedo solucionar le problema?

```
function sesion()
{
    alert("entre");
    var x = document.getElementById("inputEmail"); //capturo usuario
    var y = document.getElementById("inputPassword");//capturo contraseña
    
    //NO ENTRA
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'/xxxx/xxx?user='+ x + 'and pass='+ y ,
        data:"",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (json) {            
        },
    });

}//SE VIENE HASTA ACA
```

Comment: Desde la línea `$.ajax({` hasta el cierre de llaves se considra una única instrucción

Answer (score -1):

Primero podrías validar si esta funcionando correctamente la referencia *jQuery*
reemplazando

ejemplo:

```
var x = document.getElementById("inputEmail");
```

por

```
var x = $('#inputEmail').val();
```

como segunda opción agrégale el *callback* de error a la función, de este modo podrías validar si algo impide que funcione el llamado al recurso.

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'/xxxx/xxx?user='+ x + 'and pass='+ y ,
        data:"",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (json) {            
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
    }
});
```